# Same 16-bit CRC X-25 for any frame

Tags: crc, crc16

I'm very curious about observation I've made during development of my app.
Long story short, I was making app which reads data from smart electric meters. They have request frame like:

```
7E [hex-address] [crc1] [cmd] [crc2] 7E
```

CRC's algoritm is CRC-16/X-25, and they should calculated of whole left part of frame without `7e`, so `crc2` includes `crc1`. I've noticed that all the time `crc2` is the same for any `cmd`, even having different `hex-address`.
I've used [crccalc](https://crccalc.com/) tool to ensure. Steps to reproduce:

- put any (even any size) hex array
- calc CRC-16/X-25
- swap CRC bytes
- put this swapped CRC in end of array
- calc CRC again

This CRC would be same for any byte array. Why so? Is there any name for this phenomenon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> calc CRC again

If you append a CRC to data and calculate it again, the result is a constant value. If the CRC isn't post complemented (xorout = 0), the result is zero, but in this case it is post complemented (xorout = 0xffff), so the result is a non-zero constant, in this case 0x0f47 (assuming no errors occurred).